# Getting the result one by one from Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following files

#### index.html

```
<div><ul></ul></div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

#### main.js

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'get_db.php',
   data: {name: 'users'},
   success: function(result) {
      $(result).hide().appendTo('div ul').fadeIn(1000);
   }
});
```

#### get_db.php

```
include('db_connect.php');
$db_name = $_POST['name'];
$query   = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_name;

if($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $content .= "<li>".$row['id']." ".$row['name']."</li>";
          echo $content;
    }
}
```

#### And the question is:

#### How can I get the results 1 by 1 and append to 'div ul'?

#### In my case all the result show up at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the `<li>` elements in the response, and append each at a time with a timeout

```
$.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : 'get_db.php',
   data : {name: 'users'}
}).done(function(result) {

    $(result).each(function(index, li) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(li).hide().appendTo('div ul').fadeIn(1000);
        }, index * 300);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In get_db.php, instead of returning a HTML string which you then append the to 'div ul', you could return a JSON array that holds the rows and the data. Then in main.js iterate over the JSON array, building the HTML fragments and add them one by one as you go. This would also reduce the size of the AJAX response and allow you to use that data in other ways should you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

create a function that will start the ajax request and call again the same function once ajax process is completed

```
function ajaxload(){
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'get_db.php',
   data: {name: 'users'},
   success: function(result) {
      $(result).hide().appendTo('div ul').fadeIn(1000);
       ajaxload();
   }
 });
}
```

note: I just don't know when or how you will stop it because its base already on your requirements :)
maybe you can make a return value from ajax request and read it on the client side that will trigger the halt of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a larger table  of data more than 100 thousand then I will say get all the data at once with all the

tags style display:'none' than after that fadeIn one by one will do your work